# Dynamic FULL TEXT CONTAINSTABLE queries advice

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I am currently working on a project where I need to build dynamic CONTAINSTABLE queries. I have code in place that does something like:

```
public string BuildQuery(string searchTerms)
{
    searchTerms= searchTerms.Replace("'", "''");

    string[] words = searchTerms.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    // Here I concatenate all the words into a string separated by AND and pass that to a SQL UDF
}
```

My question is in regards to cleaning the search terms from characters that can break the SQL query. Currently I am only removing the "'" character since this will break the dynamic query.

Are there any other characters I should think of that can break the query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ASCII Key Combos will definitely break this dynamic query ,like Õ  Ž etc